# Open PDF file in Qt

Tags: qt, symbian

I want to read a .PDF file in Qt. I placed my .PDF file in the resource(qrc) folder.

How can i read the PDF file from there? I want to load a PDF file on the click of a button.

Comment: have you started working on QT ?

Answer (score 3):

Read your pdf file via `QFile`, resource access is done by prepending the path in the resource with a ":".

Qt does not natively support displaying PDF documents (it can export them using `QPrinter` though).  You can do it through third-party libraries such as [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org), see this [Qt Quarterly](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq27-poppler.html) edition on how to do it.

FWIW the resource access information is the docs, and the PDF stuff I got off Google in 30 seconds.  I expect a bit more research effort for someone with 7K+ rep points.